# Ошибка с выводом символов

Tags: php

Есть код
`$name= "Владимир"` ;
`$Len = strlen($name);`
`for($i=0;$i<$Len;$i++){`
`echo $name{$i};`
`}`
В нем все работает. Но мне нужно конкатенировать каждый символ с кавычкой:
`$name= "Владимир;`

```
`$Len = strlen($name);`
`for($i=0;$i<$Len;$i++){`
    `echo "'".$name{$i}."'";`
`}`
```

Тогда на экран выводятся только '�'�'�'�'�'�'�'�'.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name= "Владимир";

foreach (mb_str_split($name) as $char) {
    echo "'{$char}'";
}
```

Comment: У меня php такой функции не знает

Comment: @Очир потому что версия должна быть 7+